# WebDriver Selenium: Cannot Insert Username into PayPal's username box

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, paypal

I am having a hard time getting WebDriver to type in the username box of PayPal's website. I have tried by xpath, id, css but there must be something that I am missing here because it should be so simple.  The text box is the one at the very bottom of the code with input = "email"

Can someone please try it on the Paypal's website and school me on this? I am getting element not found if I just use the xpath code given by Firebug/Firepath, or if I do WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUcjm.png)

Comment: Please see the attached picture for the HTML code.

Comment: Can you post the url, by seeing the html, I can't figure out the solution.

Comment: try using by.name("login_email")

Comment: I will try that Sameer. Also here is the URL:  https://www.paypal.com/signin/?country.x=US&locale.x=en_US

Answer (score 1):

So I looked at the HTML a little bit more and realize there is a form inside it.... I was able to get it working with this code:

```
String URL = ("https://www.paypal.com/signin/?country.x=US&locale.x=en_US");
    driver.get(URL);
    WebElement form = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".main form"));
    WebElement username = form.findElement(By.id("email"));
    username.sendKeys("test");
```

Answer (score 1):

Following C# Code works fine for me. Try the same using Java, should work.

```
[Test]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        IWebElement username = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("form[name='login'] input#email"));
        username.SendKeys("anytext");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

just try this:

```
WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#email"));
email.click();
email.clear();
email.sendKeys("abc@abc.com");
```

Its work fine on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Have managed to do this by simply switching to the iframe before inserting username and password with the following C# code:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.TagName("iframe")));
var emailAddressLogin = driver.FindElement(By.Id("email"));
                emailAddressLogin.SendKeys("EnterEmailAddress");
                var password = driver.FindElement(By.Id("password"));
                password.SendKeys("EnterPassword");
```

This is using the PayPal sandbox environment.